# shell script syntax error near unexpected 'done'

Tags: linux, bash

hi im new to linux and need help with a shell script i am writing to automatically find the ip of ftp servers and copy files to them. this is the code i have but it errors when run

```
USER=anonymous
PWD=any
PORTCHECK="1"
for IP in 'sqe 6 250';
do
PORTCHECK= nmap -p21 -oG - 192.168.1.$IP | grep '21/open'
if [$PORTCHECK != "1" ]; then
ftp -p -n -i -v 192.168.1.$IP
user $USER $PWD
cd "Mounted Volume"
put foo
put bar
bye
if
CHECKPORT="1"
done
```

and the error is

```
./newscrpt: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./newscrpt: line 19: `done'
```

this is being used to copy file to multiple winCE media system after reinstall please help i cant work it out

Answer (score 3):

You meant to say `fi` instead of `if` just above `CHECKPORT` I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the structure of [if](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-if-statement-examples/) statements you will notice the that they need a `then` and `fi`. See bellow:

```
if [ conditional expression ]
then
    //stuff 
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing `for IP in 'sqe 6 250';` (broken code with `seq`), use :

```
for IP in {6..250}
```

Comment: Use indentation, it's not just an option more so when you ask for help ! that will help you & us. Also, if it was useful, consider to accept and/or upvote my response.